# how to create web service Api in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, api, service, angular8

can anyone help me how to create a web service API in angular 8.
I am in new in angular 8. I am currently working on angular 8 project. Please Help..

**from POSTMAN =>** [api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnah1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on terminal write : ng g s service name

inject httpclient which you add in appmodule as HttpClientModule

```
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
```

then simply add you methods like this

```
  getUser(id:any):Observable<User>{
return this.http.get<User>(your url from api + 'user/' + id)
```

}

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Here I have provided a sample code for creating the web service API in Angular for your reference.

Service.ts

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class UserService {
  
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private http: HttpClient) { }
  readonly BaseURI = 'http://localhost:53189';

  }
  register() {
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI + '/auth/Register', body);
  }
   
  login(formData: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI + '/auth/Login', formData);
  }

  getData(){  
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI +'/api/categories');  
  }  

  viewCategory(id: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI + '/api/categories/'+id);
  }

  postData(formData: any){  
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI +'/api/categories',formData);  
  }  
  
  putData(id: any,formData: any){  
    return this.http.put(this.BaseURI +'/api/categories/'+id,formData);  
  } 

  deleteData(id:any){  
    return this.http.delete(this.BaseURI +'/api/categories/'+ id);  
  }
  
  getProduct() {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI +'/api/products')
  }

  viewProducts(id: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI + '/api/products/'+id);
  }

  postProduct(formData: any){  
    return this.http.post(this.BaseURI +'/api/products',formData);  
  }  

  putProduct(id: any,formData: any){  
    return this.http.put(this.BaseURI +'/api/products/'+id,formData);  
  } 
  
  deleteProduct(id:any)
  {
    return this.http.delete(this.BaseURI +'/api/products/'+ id);
  }
  
  getCart(userId:any) {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI +'/api/cart/GetId/'+ userId);
  }

  addProductToCart(userId:any,productId:any) {
    
    return this.http.put(this.BaseURI +'/api/cart/add/'+userId+'/'+productId,null); 
  }
  
  decreaseQuantity(userId:any,id:any) {
    return this.http.put(this.BaseURI +'/api/cart/decreaseQuantity/'+ userId+'/' + id,null);
  }

  Productbycategory(categoryId: any) {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI +'/api/products/Getproduct/' + categoryId );
     
  }
    getCategory() {
    return this.http.get(this.BaseURI +'/api/categories');
    }
  
  // getUserProfile() {
  //   var tokenheader= new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization':'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('token')});

  //   return this.http.get(this.BaseURI + '/UserProfile',{headers:tokenheader});
  // }


  
  }
```